Create a spike raster plot from multiple npy files
I am new to python and I need help with creating a raster plot. I have 16 electrodes and I am conducting the experiments in seconds for about 1600 seconds. this is the code I have.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Parameters
n_electrodes = 16  # Number of electrodes
desired_num_bins = 1600  # Number of bins you want on the x-axis
x_max = 1600  # Maximum value for the x-axis in seconds

# Load spike train data from each .npy file and determine the maximum duration
spike_trains = []
max_duration = 0
for i in range(1, n_electrodes + 1):
    spike_train = np.load(f'electrode {i}.npy')
    spike_trains.append(spike_train)
    if len(spike_train) > max_duration:
        max_duration = len(spike_train)

# Calculate bin size based on total duration and desired number of bins
bin_size = max_duration / desired_num_bins

# Calculate the number of bins based on the calculated bin_size
max_bins = int(x_max / bin_size)

# Pad spike trains to the length corresponding to max_bins
for i in range(len(spike_trains)):
    if len(spike_trains[i]) < max_bins:
        spike_trains[i] = np.pad(spike_trains[i], (0, max_bins - len(spike_trains[i])), 'constant')

# Convert list to numpy array
spike_trains = np.array(spike_trains)

# Create raster plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

# Plot spikes using vlines
for neuron in range(n_electrodes):
    spike_times = np.where(spike_trains[neuron])[0]  # Get the indices (time bins) where spikes occur
    
    # Convert spike times from bins to seconds
    spike_times_in_seconds = spike_times * bin_size
    
    # Plot vertical lines for each spike
    ax.vlines(spike_times_in_seconds, neuron + 0.5, neuron + 1.5, color='black', linewidth=1)

ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
ax.set_ylabel('Electrode')
ax.set_title(f'Spike Raster Plot for {n_electrodes} Electrodes')
ax.set_xlim(0, x_max)
ax.set_ylim(0.5, n_electrodes + 0.5)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(1, n_electrodes + 1))

# Adjust the x-axis tick labels to be in seconds
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(100))  # Set major ticks every 100 seconds
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(10))   # Set minor ticks every 10 seconds

plt.show()

It isn't generating a correct plot. Everything is squished to the side and not spaced out correctly. I have data in the 1000 but it is not visible.

